# To lose by theft

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific term for the loss of something by theft, or the non-specific suffering of theft? I am looking for something like "lose" but more specific.

Comment: Did you look up 'theft' in an on-line thesaurus to see what related terms there might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *[forfeit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forfeit?show=1&t=1330357862)*?

> 1:  to lose or lose the right to especially by some error, offense, or crime
>
> 2:  to subject to confiscation as a forfeit; also : abandon, give up

Are you looking for a general getter/setter name, or will there be a separate function for each item lost?

Comment: I don't think _forfeit_ applies.  Sure, the definition says _by crime_, but in this case, the individual is the _perpetrator_ of the crime, not the victim.  "He forfeited his medical license after amputating the wrong leg," e.g.

Comment: I was not clear, my apologies. The verb does apply to the victim, forfeit is the best answer I've recieved so far. And yes, this is a getter/setter name.

Comment: "Forfeit" is wrong. Theft is the illegal taking on a good or service, "forfeit" is the legal taking of a good or service. There is no overlap in meaning at all.

Answer (score 3):

Why not *stolen*? My computer was *stolen* last night by a very clever *thief*.

Note that *stolen* is not only a past participle of *steal*, but also an adjective. Therefore you can safely use it to describe anything in present tense,   like:

> My computer is stolen since the first great theft on our street.

Comment: Yes, but the subject of *to be stolen* is the thing that was actually taken. If you want the victim to be the subject, you can say *"I was robbed"*, but I have to say I don't particularly like *"I was robbed of my computer last night"*. And I'm afraid your *"My computer is stolen since.."* is not a well-formed English sentence.

Comment: You might not like "I was robbed of my computer" but there really is nothing wrong with it. Matter of style, and it isn't awkward.

Comment: I was burgled yesterday.

Comment: My question is for the naming of a function in programming. It would be player.lose("Brick"), but for vocabulary's sake I'd like to be more specific.

Comment: +1 for 'burgled'.  There's a special place in my heart for that word.

Comment: Note that burglary is a very specific form of theft.

Answer (score 2):

It applies only in a specific domain, but the correct term in retail is "shrinkage."

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a noun, then you suffered a *robbery* or a *burglary* (if the item was stolen from a building or car), or a *mugging* if it was stolen from you personally under threat of violence.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the passive voice:

> My car was stolen.

Or you can replace *be* with *get*:

> My car got stolen.